# I've upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to 2012. Project references to SqlClr projects are looking for my project's dll, but with no file extension

Tags: upgrade, visual-studio-2012, sqlclr, project-reference

Say I have a SqlClr project called MySqlClrProject, which builds the file MySqlClrProject.dll. I've observed that the Build output file name can be either MySqlClrProject or MySqlClrProject.dll, but either way will produce a file named MySqlClrProject.dll.  I also have another project in my solution, called MyClassLibrary, which has a project reference to MySqlClrProject.  When I build MyClassLibrary, I'll see this error:

CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\devStuff\MySqlClrProject\bin\Debug\MySqlClrProject' could not be found

Before that, in the output, I see this:

ResolveAssemblyReferences:
5>  Primary reference "MySqlClrProject".

5>      Could not find dependent files. Expected file "C:\devStuff\MySqlClrProject\bin\Debug\MySqlClrProject" does not exist.

5>      Could not find dependent files. Expected file "C:\devStuff\MySqlClrProject\bin\Debug\MySqlClrProject" does not exist.

5>      Resolved file path is "C:\devStuff\MySqlClrProject\bin\Debug\MySqlClrProject".

5>      Reference found at search path location "".

5>      Found related file "C:\devStuff\MySqlClrProject\bin\Debug\MySqlClrProject.pdb".

5>      Found related file "C:\devStuff\MySqlClrProject\bin\Debug\MySqlClrProject.xml".

5>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "".

If I add a post build step that copies MySqlClrProject.dll to MySqlClrProject, all is well.  Alternatively, if I reference the dll directly, as opposed to using a project reference, then, again, it works fine.  I'd really rather not go either of those routes...

Anyway, has anyone else seen this?  Anything I might be doing wrong?  I know VS2012 is very new, and they've changed a lot when it comes to SqlClr projects, but I'm wondering if the problem is on my side or Microsoft's.

Thanks.